# Does mongoose.mongo.MongoClient.connect() works without mongo shell?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, mongoose, replicaset

I am connecting to the mongo servers that are not localhost. I am using mongoose.
And in some moment I needed to connect with mongo native driver so I am doing it like:

```
mongoose.mongo.MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, conn) {});
```

but `conn` object is `null`.

Recently I changed servers structure, and now all mongo databases are remote, and on my new node machines I do not have mongo shell installed at all... In first all was working fine and connection uri was:

```
mongodb://x.x.x.x:27017/database,mongodb://y.y.y.y,mongodb://z.z.z.z
```

where `x.x.x.x:27017` was primary, after some time due the break of the initial primary, new primary has been elected, and now I am starting with the same uri, but connection object is `null` and I do not know why...

is there somebody that had similar problem? or maybe solution or idea....

Comment: The `Mongoose ODM` (or any MongoDB drivers) do not rely on the `mongo` shell to connect. Drivers exchange messages directly with a `mongod` server (or `mongos`, for sharded clusters) using the [MongoDB Wire Protocol](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/). I would suggest trying to connect from a `mongo` shell on your machine (or wherever you are running the Mongoose code from) to see if there is a general connectivity issue. It's possible that your remote `mongod` instance is blocking connections via a firewall or `bind_ip` directive.

Comment: solution was that connection uri for the MongoClient was not correct... I was using same uri like I used in mongoose, but correct one was this one: `mongodb://x.x.x.x:27017,y.y.y.y:27017,z.z.z.z:27017/database`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection uri was wrong:

instead:

```
mongodb://x.x.x.x:27017/database,mongodb://y.y.y.y,mongodb://z.z.z.z,{options}
```

for native driver MongoClient I should used:

```
mongodb://x.x.x.x:27017,y.y.y.y:27017,z.z.z.z:27017/database?opt1=o1&opt2=o2
```

this is where I was found this solution:
[MongoClient.connect](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#a-replicaset-connect-using-no-acknowledgment-by-default-and-readpreference-for-secondary)